# thymeleaf not displaying properly

Tags: thymeleaf

Can Some tell me what is wrong with thes Code.It only show the first row and the table head information.thks

```
`<div class="container">
<div th:if="${not #lists.isEmpty(products)}">
    <h2>List of Products</h2>
    <table class="table table-striped" th:width="700px">
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Image Url</th>
        </tr>
        <tr th:each="product : ${products}">
            <td th:text="${product.id}"></td>
            <td th:text="${product.description}"></td>
            <td th:text="${product.price}"></td>
            <td th:text="${product.imageUrl}"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: You have two opening div and one closing div. Is this an error in the copy-paste that your have made here?Could you please copy and paste your whole page html code? In addition, how many products do you have?Can you post the code of your controller?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to say: **if the area is NOT EMPTY than show**...if so you don't have the thymeleaf setup correct.  For a SUPER easy fix I just check one of the elements in my array and render the whole div hidden if there is no data otherwise it shows

You would want to do something like this then:

```
th:if="${!products.id.isEmpty()}"
```

This says - if the id of your products list is not empty show the whole div.

BUT if you want to check to see if the whole thing is NULL, you would do something this:

```
th:if="${products != null}"
```

That says - if your array has no data than don't show.